# Getting "Access violation executing location" error

Tags: ida, assembly, memory

I am trying to execute this assembly function. But after calling **Test_init** function, I am getting "Access violation executing location"  error at line "add     esp,4".

```
sub_402110  proc near       ; CODE XREF: _main+37p

var_AC      = dword ptr -0ACh
var_A8      = dword ptr -0A8h
var_A4      = dword ptr -0A4h
var_A0      = dword ptr -0A0h
var_9C      = dword ptr -9Ch
var_95      = byte ptr -95h
var_94      = byte ptr -94h
Dest        = byte ptr -38h
var_14      = byte ptr -14h
var_4       = dword ptr -4

        push    ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, 0ACh
        xor eax, ebp
        mov [ebp+var_4], eax
        mov [ebp+var_A4], offset aHelloWorld ; "Hello World"
        lea eax, [ebp+var_94]
        push    eax
        call    ds:Test_Init
        add     esp,4
        mov ecx, [ebp+var_A4]
        mov [ebp+var_A0], ecx
        mov edx, [ebp+var_A0]
```

Can anyone please help me to way out from this problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could it be that ESP got modified to an address that's incorrect by Test_Init? Is it packed? Can you run it without the debugger attached? You should provide more information.

Comment: No, it is not packed. Test_Init is a function inside a .lib file.

Comment: does Test_Init call VirtualProtect on the page that called it?  Perhaps the execute bit was cleared for the page.

Comment: It's pretty hard to help you without knowing what the Test_Init call does..